# Is a $\chi^2$ test appropriate where data points are themselves totals?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

My is a series of individuals have attempted a test. They can fail this test for multiple reasons. Furthermore, on an test, a fail can be awarded multiple times for one reason, i.e.:

Steve:   1,0,2,1 Jane: 2,0,0,1
are both valid entries for a test with four reasons.

Having said that, many of the reasons are effectively a boolean, i.e., the column can hold either a 1 or a 0 only.

I'm interested in a subset of the rows of this table, e.g., Steve and his family. Specifically, I want to know if the distribution of the mean of each column (reason) within the subset differs significantly from the equivalent distribution for the whole population.

Is a $\chi^2$ test with the null hypothesis that the subset distribution matches the whole population distribution appropriate here?

Comment: Please edit to clarify: (1) By "subset", do you mean a set of rows, as opposed to a set of columns? (2) Wouldn't you want to compare the means rather than the sums, since the bounds on the sum depend on the number of subjects?

Comment: @Kodiologist Yes, thanks, edited to follow these suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the point is just to compare means, there's no need to compare entire distributional forms; you can use mean-specific tests. For each failure reason (column), you can frame the problem as comparing the means of two samples: one sample is Steve and his family, and the other sample is every other row of your data. You can test whether these sample means are significantly different with a two-sample $t$-test. It's probably best to use Welch's $t$-test, because the assumption of equal variances is unrealistic.

One could argue that Welch's $t$-test isn't appropriate, either, because the dependent variable clearly isn't normally distributed. To avoid this issue, you can use a permutation test instead. The usual nonparametric answer to the two-sample $t$-test, the Mann-Whitney $U$-test, doesn't compare means, so that's probably not a good choice.

Comment: Per [this link](https://pythonfordatascience.org/welch-t-test-python-pandas/) the dependent variable should be continuous. These variables are counts of failures and therefore integers. Surely that means the continuity clause is violated?

Comment: @lovelyzoo Specifically, the assumption is that the dependent variable is normally distributed. You're quite right that that's not true here; however, the usual nonparametric answer to the two-sample $t$-test, the Mann-Whitney $U$-test, doesn't compare means, so that's probably not a good choice. One thing you could try if you're worried about this is a permutation test.

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion with @Kodiologist, permutation testing seems to be the best way to go. More about which can be found [here](http://danielnee.com/2015/01/random-permutation-tests/).

Comment: The thing is that @Kodiologist's initial answer suggests Welch's t-test. It was in the subsequent discussion that the permutation test was suggested. For that reason, I thought it better to post this answer so that a future reader is directed to the most appropriate test.

Comment: @Kodiologist, feel free to edit the original answer as per gung's suggestion. I'll then mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @lovelyzoo Done.